# Make image slideshow in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, animation, slideshow

I'm trying to create an image slideshow just like this one on this page: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1914
If you mouseover the image of the tablet, two arrows appear and you may slide through these images.

How to achieve this with wpf?
I want to create it just like on the page, I press the right arrow and the current image moves left out of sight and the new image comes to the center from the right.

The application should be resolution independet, so working with a canvas isn't possible I guess.

Comment: Have have you tried so far? This page is not for asking people to write a program for you, but to help you with problems you encounter.
You can use very simple WPF animations to accomplish something like that.

Answer (score 3):

To give a general answer to that question without writing the code for you(, which is your task):

Create a `Grid` with the size of one image. Create a `Canvas` with the `HeightProperty` set to the height of the images and the `WidthProperty` to the sum of the width*amount of images.

Next thing, add two images for the arrows and the canvas as children to your grid and position them correctly.

Second last thing. Create an event for the grid `MouseEnter` to change the `IsVisible` property of the arrows to `true` and one for `MouseLeave` where it is set to `false`.

Last thing. Create events for `LeftMouseButtonDown` for the two arrow images that will trigger a animation that changes the `Margin.Left` property of the canvas by the width of one image.